# Material-UI collapse animation within table will insert div's and throws validateDOMNesting warning

Tags: css, reactjs, html-table, material-ui

I have a table filled with data and I would like to have a transition when adding/deleting an item. It's a ReactJS project with Material-UI.

I want to achieve the same effect as in their [example](https://mui.com/material-ui/transitions/#transitiongroup). They are using a List component, but I'm using a table for it. The code looks like this:

```
<TableBody>
                            <TransitionGroup component={null} id="ffff">
                                {(data?.maintenanceRequests || []).map((form) => (
                                    <Collapse key={form.id} component={TableRow}>

                                        <TableCell>{form.building}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell>{form.dueDate ? form.dueDate : '-'}</TableCell>
                                        <TableCell align="right">
                                            <IconButton component={Link} to={`request/${form.id}`}>
                                                <EditIcon />
                                            </IconButton>
                                            <IconButton onClick={() => deleteReq({ variables: { deleteMaintenanceRequestId: form.id }, refetchQueries: [{ query: GET_MAINTENANCE_REQUESTS }] })}>
                                                <DeleteIcon />
                                            </IconButton>
                                        </TableCell>

                                    </Collapse>
                                ))}
                            </TransitionGroup>
                        </TableBody>
```

By using this piece of code I will receive the warnings:
`Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <td> cannot appear as a child of <div>.` And `Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a child of <tr>.`

As you can see I already defined which component the  and  should wrap. While inspecting the element I see the  component insert 2 nested div's. So it's clear where the warnings coming from. The real question is how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't encourage you to use the mui table for this use case but here is a solution

```
import {
  Collapse,
  IconButton,
  TableCell,
  TableRow,
  Table,
  TableContainer,
  Paper,
  Button
} from '@mui/material'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { TransitionGroup, CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group'

import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Delete'

const data = [
  { id: 1, building: 'A', dueDate: '12/12/12' },
  { id: 2, building: 'b', dueDate: '12/12/12' },
  { id: 3, building: 'c', dueDate: '12/12/12' },
  { id: 4, building: 'd', dueDate: '12/12/12' },
  { id: 5, building: 'e', dueDate: '12/12/12' },
  { id: 6, building: 'f', dueDate: '12/12/12' },
  { id: 7, building: 'g', dueDate: '12/12/12' },
  { id: 8, building: 'h', dueDate: '12/12/12' }
]

const alpha = 'ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

const Test = () => {
  // const textFieldClasses: any = textfieldUseStyles()c
  const [ListData, setListData] = useState(data)

  const handleAddData = () => {
    const newData = [
      ...ListData,
      {
        id: ListData.length + 1,
        building: alpha.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * alpha.length)),
        dueDate: '12/12/12'
      }
    ]
    setListData(newData)
  }

  const handleRemoveData = (id: number) => {
    const newData = ListData.filter(item => item.id !== id)
    setListData(newData)
  }

  return (
    <TransitionGroup>
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="simple table">
          <TransitionGroup>
            {ListData.map(form => (
              <Collapse key={form.id}>
                <TableRow className="item">
                  <TableCell>{form.building}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{form.dueDate ? form.dueDate : '-'}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">
                    <IconButton onClick={() => handleRemoveData(form.id)}>
                      <DeleteIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </Collapse>
            ))}
          </TransitionGroup>
        </Table>
        <Button sx={{ mt: 2, width: '100%' }} onClick={handleAddData}>
          Add Item
        </Button>
      </TableContainer>
    </TransitionGroup>
  )
}

export default Test
```

Comment: Hey, thanks I tried it out but still get the same error unfortunately. What do you recommend for using instead of the mui table? I guess a regular List component. While that works, I can't achieve the same grid layout unfortunately ( few columns ).